# why react-native take a long time to start?

Tags: react-native

when I start npm sometimes get a accurate result but sometimes it takes a long time and after many hours it was the same problem.

- npm version: 5.8.0
- node version: 6.3.1
- react-native-cli: 2.0.1
- react-native: 0.54.0

[image]